# Is there a better way to write this SparkSQL statement?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What are the best ways to write SparkSQL statements?

Any suggestions on such statements:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df_final = df_01\
            .select(df_01['*'],
                    psf.when(df_01.record_two>\
                             df_01.record_three,
                             df_01.record_two)
                       .otherwise(df_01.record_three)\
                       .alias("some_new_alias"))\
            .where("some_field > 1000")\
            .where((df_01.record_one.isin(df_red01.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_blue01.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_violet01.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_green01.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_black01.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_white01.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_red02.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_blue02.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_violet02.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_green02.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_black02.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_white02.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_blue03.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_violet03.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_green03.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_black03.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_violet04.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_green04.record_one)==False) |\
                   (df_01.record_one.isin(df_violet04.record_one)==False))\
            .select("record_one", "some_new_alias")


df_another_test_frame = df_jibber01\
                         .select(df_jibber01.field01,
                                 df_jibber01.field02,
                                 df_jibber01.field03,
                                 df_jibber01.field04,
                                 df_jibber01.field05,
                                 df_jibber01.field06,
                                 df_jibber01.field07,
                                 df_jibber01.field08,
                                 df_jibber01.field09,
                                 psf.when(df_jibber01.field04 <= 100,
                                          psf.round(2000*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))\
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field05 >= 1,
                                          psf.round(2000*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))                                     
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field06 >= 2,
                                          psf.round(2000*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))                                     
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field04 <= 3,
                                          psf.round(20*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))                                     
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field05 >= 4,
                                          psf.round(20*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))       
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field06 >= 5,
                                          psf.round(20*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field04 <= 6,
                                          psf.round(9999*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field05 >= 7,
                                          psf.round(9999*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))
                                    .when(df_jibber01.field06 >= 8,
                                          psf.round(9999*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))                                     
                                    .otherwise(psf.round(9999*df_jibber01.field10/59, 10))\
                                    .alias("field11")
                                )
```

There are multiple "where" and "when" conditions. Is there a cleaner way to write? I have 100s of such statements.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem ,best practice is to keep this rules in separate file or table for example for df_another_test_frame

```
rules_table(ruled_id int ,field04_from int,field04_to int ,field05_from int 
,field05_to int ,field06_from int,field06_to int,ponder_for_field_10 decimal)
```

and then you always have generic  same join with rules_table,independent of changes and you can store more rules for different tasks.

If you can switch to SparkSession.sql you can make dynamic sql and add rules from text file directly to sql string without join. Problem with that approach  is that someone from development department have to maintain that file.

If you have simple rules_table  than customer or a business analyst can maintain rules.